# Which loss function to use for autoencoders, if the inputs are binary features [0/1]?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, loss-functions, autoencoders

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
A|B|C
-|-|-
1|0|0
0|1|0
1|1|0
0|1|1
.|.|.
.|.|.
.|.|.
```

I want to use the above dataset as input to an autoencoder. I did do some research and found that the best loss function to use given such a dataset is the [sigmoid cross entropy loss function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits). I used the implementation in tensorflow. The following is the description of the loss function:

```
Measures the probability error in discrete classification tasks in 
which each class is independent and not mutually exclusive. For 
instance, one could perform multilabel classification where a picture 
can contain both an elephant and a dog at the same time.
```

Can the above loss function be used? If yes, are there any limitations?

Comment: Yes, cross entropy makes sense. Output values must range from 0 to 1, and are interpreted as probabilities. So, sigmoidal output units make sense.

Comment: @user20160 But if I am using the cross entropy loss then wouldn't the features of the reconstruction output (x') be considered independent of each other? Because the loss function considers each class to be independent of each other.